# How to format Java code di Eclipse like IntelliJ

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 2022-06 and I'm trying to format a piece of code like IntelliJ does.

This is **what I would like**:

```java
// 1
@Test
void create() throws Exception {
   mockMvc.perform( post( "/api/v1/create" )
               .accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
               .content( "{ }" )
               .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ) )
         .andDo( print() )
         .andExpect( content().contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ) )
         ;
}
```

But that is what I get :-(

```java
// 2
@Test
void create() throws Exception {
   mockMvc.perform( post( "/api/v1/create" )
         .accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
         .content( "{ }" )
         .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ) )
         .andDo( print() )
         .andExpect( content().contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ) );
}
```

or

```java
// 3
@Test
void create() throws Exception {
   mockMvc
         .perform( post( "/api/v1/create" )
               .accept( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
               .content( "{ }" )
               .contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ) )
         .andDo( print() )
         .andExpect( content().contentType( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ) );
}
```

I tried every combinations of that option without find solution:

[image]

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Your last code snippet looks very close to the expected result. Is the only problem the unwanted line break before `.perform` or also the missing (unusual) line break before `;`?

Comment: I know, but I don't want that line break. It might be nice here,  but awful to see somewhere else ... ;-)

Comment: Okay, but what about the `;`? Does IntelliJ put it really on a separate line (which looks a bit strange to me). And if yes, do you want this also in Eclipse or is your question only about how to avoid the line break before `.perform`?

Comment: What I want is to avoid line break before `.perform`, I do not care about `;`.
I found that with my current configuration (code n. 2), if I manually add a line break before `.perform` I automatically get code n.3. So I can decide where and when apply it. :-)

Thanks for the support!